# Solving the system $x\sqrt{y} + y\sqrt{x} = 30$, $x\sqrt{x} + y\sqrt{y} = 35$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

I'm stuck on this problem:
$$ \begin{cases} x\sqrt{y} + y\sqrt{x} = 30 \\ x\sqrt{x} + y\sqrt{y} = 35\end{cases} $$

I've not solved this kind of problem before. I tried formula for square of sum and also sum of cubes to possibly isolate an expression. I've also tried substituting $ \sqrt{xy}$ or some other expression with a new variable, but couldn't really get anywhere.

P.S. I'm aware that you can easily get the answers by just trying to plug in the numbers, I'm looking for a more general, algebraic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From

$$\begin{cases} x\sqrt{y} + y\sqrt{x} = 30 & \ \ (a)\\ x\sqrt{x} + y\sqrt{y} = 35& \ \ (b)\end{cases}$$

$3 \times$(a) + (b) gives :

$$(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^3=5^3\ \ \iff \ \  \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=5 \ \tag{1}$$

Besides, (b) - (a) gives :

$$x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})-y(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})=5 \ \iff$$

$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})=5 \tag{2}$$

Taking (1) into account in (2), on gets :

$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\pm1\tag{3}$$

Gathering (1) and (3), we obtain easily the two solutions :

$$(x,y)=(4,9) \ \text{and} \ (x,y)=(9,4) $$

as confirmed by the following graphical representation ((a) in blue and (b) in red) :

[image]

Comment: Wow, now it seems a lot easier, thanks.
  I'm thinking about expressing $\sqrt{x}$ as $(5 - \sqrt {y}) $ and plugging it into the first equation. Is there perhaps an easier way i'm not seeing?

Comment: I think you should now substract the second equation from the first one to obtain : $(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})^2(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})=...$ and then plug the result $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\pm 5$ in it in order to get an expression of $\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Alright, got it, thanks again. By the way, where did the plus or minus sign come from? Was it a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: The $\pm$ was erroneous...

Comment: I just gave a complete answer.